# How to save stripe user info for next transaction in Django Rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, stripe-payments

Is it possible to store user data after first payment of stripe for next transaction so that he doesn't need to provide card information again like `FIVERR`? I actually want a system to save the card information with Django rest framework. You can see my stripe payment system. I actually totally confused between it possible or not. Please tell me what response will come and what info will come as input from the frontend.

```
import stripe

# Set your API key
stripe.api_key = 'sk_test_51N'
c_amount = 1
# Create a PaymentIntent with the order amount and currency
intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
    amount=100*c_amount,
    currency='usd',
    payment_method_types=['card'],
)


print("client_secret:",intent['client_secret'])
print("amount:",intent['amount'])
print("payment_id:",intent['id'])
```

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment explains how to process a payment and save the card used in the payment for use in future payments.

Comment: oke thank,, let me try it